# How to shift html elements toward left using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a button in my html. With clicking on it I want to shift insert a green box ("div") before the button. Is there a way in jquery to do this? I wrote the code below but it is not working. The new element appears on my button.

```
click: function () {
    var oldLeft = parseInt($('#addButton').css('left'));
    var newFU = $('<div class="fu"></div>');
    newFU.insertBefore("#addButton");
    var newLeft=  oldLeft + newFU.width();
    $("#addButton").css("left",  newLeft);
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

related css is like this:

```
div .fu {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #19833F;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.addButton{
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: white;
    color: #20ff5c;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered to build your desired view in a mockup and then to create it dinamically by adding and removing content? By reading your styles, it suggests you are not close to the desired behavior anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by defining the button with relative position:

.

```
addButton{
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: white;
    color: #20ff5c;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```